# OpenGL ES 2 glGetActiveAtrib and non floats

Tags: c++, c, directx, opengl-es-2.0

I'm porting an engine from DX9/10/11 over to OpenGL ES 2.  I'm having a bit of a problem with glGetActiveAttrib though.

According to the [docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetActiveAttrib.xml) the type returned can only be one of the following:

> The symbolic constants GL_FLOAT, GL_FLOAT_VEC2, GL_FLOAT_VEC3,
>   GL_FLOAT_VEC4, GL_FLOAT_MAT2, GL_FLOAT_MAT3, or GL_FLOAT_MAT4 may be
>   returned.

This seems t imply that you cannot have an integer vertex attribute?  Am I missing something?  Does this really mean you HAVE to implement every thing as floats?  Does this mean I can't implement a colour as 4 byte values?

If so, this seems very strange as this would be a horrific waste of memory ... if not, can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes must be declared as floats in GLSL ES shader. But you can pass to them SHORT's or other supported values listed [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml). The conversion will happen automatically.

Comment: I'd actually just started wondering if that was the case ... Cheers! :)